# How do I style a custom namespaced element with CSS

Tags: html, css, jsf

I'm on a project where these custom template elements are inserted into the HTML, but they're used later in the JS and they're not meant to display on the page.

```
<b:template tag="cite">
  <cite><b:content>default content</b:content></cite>
</b:template>
```

I tried to hide them in CSS like this:

```
b:template {display:none;}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.  Is there a way to style these namespaced elements?

Comment: I see that the question above has the same answer, but the keywords are so different in it that I wasn't able to find it when I needed to find the answer to this question.  I did try to search.

Comment: I added the tag JSF in case somebody lands here and doesn't know where to find more questions about this type of template.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to escape the `:` character like so:

```
b\:template {display:none;}
```

Comment: ah, that was easy!  thanks.